# compare two columns in awk and print values from lookup files into output file

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have two files with first file having ~16000 files and the second file is lookup file having ~4000 lines.

Sample contents of file1 is given below:

```
id,title,name,value,details
01,23456,   ,   ,abcdefg
02,23456,   ,   ,abcdefg
03,12345,   ,   ,abcdefg
04,34534,   ,   ,abcdefg
...
```

Sample contents of lookup file file2 is given below:

```
sno,title,name,value
1,23456,abc,xyz
2,12345,cde,efg
3,34534,543,234
```

Now my requirement is compare column 2 of file1 in the lookup file and insert the values of column3 and column4 from lookup file into new output file.

The output file should look like below:

```
id,title,name,value,details
01,23456,abc,xyz,abcdefg
02,23456,abc,xyz,abcdefg
03,12345,cde,efg,abcdefg
04,34534,543,234,abcdefg
```

I did try few iterations by looking at existing questions but didn't get the results I desired. Any solution with awk would be much helpful.

Comment: find some articles about the `join` command. `man join` may help. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, could you please provide a solution in awk as I am expected to use awk in my script?

Comment: Contrary to what you seem to expect, StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. You're expected to include your attempt to solve the problem, and any relevant error messages. Good luck on your classwork.

Comment: Hi Shellter, thanks for your inputs. As i have mentioned in my statement I did try multiple attempts but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Will ensure to mention the codes which I have tried now on.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat vino.awk
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
NR==FNR { name[$2]=$3; value[$2]=$4; next }
{ print $1, $2, name[$2], value[$2], $5 }

$ cat file1
id,title,name,value,details
01,23456,   ,   ,abcdefg
02,23456,   ,   ,abcdefg
03,12345,   ,   ,abcdefg
04,34534,   ,   ,abcdefg

$ cat file2
sno,title,name,value
1,23456,abc,xyz
2,12345,cde,efg
3,34534,543,234

$ awk -f vino.awk file2 file1
id,title,name,value,details
01,23456,abc,xyz,abcdefg
02,23456,abc,xyz,abcdefg
03,12345,cde,efg,abcdefg
04,34534,543,234,abcdefg
```

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't put any explanation, but the only real trick is the `NR==FNR` idiom, which often applies perfectly to these sorts of "join" problems. For a good explanation search for "Two-file processing" in http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ and/or ask me any questions here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an awk oneliner:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {n[$2]=$3;v[$2]=$4} FNR!=NR{OFS=","; print $1,$2,n[$2],v[$2],$5}' file2 file1
```

The idea is to process in two passes, first for file2 to store all of the names and values, then for file1, to print out each line including the collected names and values.

Comment: Set OFS in the BEGIN section (`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} ...'`), not every time a file1 line is read. Also use `next` in the first block instead of testing the negation of the first condition before the second block. Of course, then your answer will be identical to the one @jas posted earlier so you may as well delete this one.

Comment: Can you suggest a reason to do those things (performance, readability), or is this just nitpicking?

Comment: performance (don't perform an action once per input line when you could do it just once total), readability (if you need 2 variables set to the same value, it improves clarity to set them together and if you need to init a global variable it's clearer to do it at the start of the program rather than in the middle of it), and maintainability (since FS and OFS MUST have the same value they should be set together, not set to the same value independently,...

Comment: ...and you never want to explicitly state the precise negation of some other stated condition because then when the positive condition changes you need to find the negation and change that too in precisely opposite way or vice-versa). Sorry it was too much text for one comment block.

Comment: Although some (me :) might argue that: performance impact is negligible (so do what is more readable), putting OFS where it is USED is more readable than at the start, and explicit expressions for the actions is clearer than using next.  So, I don't agree.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR==FNR {a[$2]=$3","$4;next} {print $1,$2,a[$2],$5;}' file2 file1
```